# SQL Combining 2 result sets in an ordered way

Tags: sql

Is there a way to order 2 queries into a single result set?

More specifically, if I had 2 queries :

```
select 'line',product, numeric_value from numbertable order by product;

select 'Total',product, sum(numeric_value) from numbertable group by product;
```

Is there a way to combine the two queries so that the result set would look like this:

```
    Type      Product      numeric_value

    line      item1        23
    line      item1        57
    line      item1        23
    Total     item1        103
    line      item5        20
    line      item5        50
    line      item5        60
    Total     item5        130
    ...
```

Basically, I'm looking to list all of the item records of a product, then show a sum for them, then list all the item records of the next product, etc.

Is there a way to do this, or is it an impossible task?
Thanks :)

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it

Comment: In this case, I'd perform a `UNION` and then `ORDER BY product, type`. This just works because `Total` is larger than `line`.

Comment: Rolan What database server?

Comment: This is using an oracle 11g server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many databases, you can do this with `rollup`.  However, since you've gotten this far:

```
select *
from ((select 'line' as which, product, numeric_value from numbertable
      ) union all
      (select 'Total', product, sum(numeric_value) from numbertable group by product
      )
     ) t
order by Product, which
```

The `order by Product, which`, brings all the product lines together.  The "Total" is last due to the ordering.

Comment: Surprisingly, in SQL Server, you can do this like so: `(SELECT a = 1, b = 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3, 4) ORDER BY a;` so in that DBMS one may not need the outer `SELECT` or a derived table alias name.

Comment: @ErikE . . . I almost always write my `unions` in the `from` clause.  That way, I don't have to remember that `where` applies to the last query, but `order by` applies to the full set.  And that `limit` applies to the full set but `group by` applies only to the last query.

Comment: That's what the parentheses are for in my code above! You get the exact same effect of seeing that the `ORDER BY` only applies to the entire set, and any `GROUP BY` does not.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks.  It seems that I have much to learn about arranging sql to do my bidding :)